# Notepad++ find and replace

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I need help getting this:

```
test1|test2|2017-04-28|11:19:01|string|test3|3|FINDTHISWORD|2003-10-15 16:00:00.000|
```

from this:

```
test1|test2|2017-04-28|11:19:01|string|test3|3|FINDTHISWORD|2003-10-15|16:00:00.000|
```

basically, I need to find the "FIDNTHISWORD" then move 12 to the right and replace the "|" with space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to Search (menu), Replace...
2. Set Search Mode to "Regular Expression"
3. Find what: `(FINDTHISWORD...........)\|`
4. Replace with: `\1` (backslash, one, space)
5. Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

**Explanation:** `(FINDTHISWORD...........)\|`

- The parentheses indicate a group you will paste later
- `FINDTHISWORD...........` match FINDTHISWORD followed by eleven characters
- `\|` followed by a literal pipe character
- `\1(space)` output the pattern with parentheses followed by a space

For more info: [Regular Expressions - Notepad++ Wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)